# Spring MVC test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to learn spring, and I cannot find enough resources for testing, sorry for my English:)
I have a controller class which returns ResponseEntity

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository rep;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOrderById(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        Order or = rep.findById(id).get();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(or); }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
        rep.save(order);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(order);
}
```

I am trying to test with

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @WebMvcTest(OrderController.class)
 public class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Test
    public void shouldPresistOrder() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/ORD00001").accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());}}
```

I get status expected<200> but was<404>
Do I need to create an Order instance first, because it is a quite large class with lots of variables ?
What are the ways of testing endpoints? Are there any books or online resources just for MVC testing purposes? Many thanks

Comment: In your case, you may call the `addOrder` firstly and then call the `getOrderById` with the `order id` created earlier. But where do you store your orders？In memory or some kind of databases? If it's a database, you may need to mock/start the db before tests begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the **OrderRepository** class but there are no rules associated with it, 
create a dummy **Order** and Add the rule like this 
`when(orderRepository.findById(<id in the dummy order>)).thenReturn(DummyOrder)`
In this way, you are setting the rules for OrderRepository to behave according to your needs.

Comment: Do I need to populate Order class manually? Order order = new Order(); order.setId;  order.setName; ....

Comment: I get : "is not applicable for the arguments (Order)" Order order = Mockito.mock(Order.class); Mockito.when(orderRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(order);

Comment: Yes you need to populate the Order class Manually
please note order returned should be Optional Order object

Comment: @Test
    public void shouldPresistOrder() throws Exception {
  
   Order o = new Order("ORD00001", "ABCD"....)
   Optional<Order> order = Optional.of(o);
   when(orderRepository.findById("/ORD00001")).thenReturn(order);this.mockMvc.perform(get("/ORD00001").accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
I still get status expected<200> but was<404> ?

Comment: Can you debug the code and check **rep** object id is the same as it your controller?

Comment: Thank you Nayan, I still dont understand need for Optional, but it finally worked:)

Comment: the Optional is because `rep.findById(id)` returns an **Optional** type - In controller if the rule for `rep.findById(id)` is not returning Optional then `rep.findById(id).get()` would fail hence to replicate the complete scenario we need the **Optional**